# Setting for how close the text appears to the eye - depth issues

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

The text shown on the eyeglasses are appearing about 20-25 centimeters away from the eye I guess but is there any setting to change it in the code? If I want to move the text around in depth (further away or closer to the wearer) is it possible to do that?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to adjust depth in the application code.

It is done using;
utils.setScreenDepth(depth);

You can check SampleDisplaySetting, in SmartEyeglass SDK samples, to learn how it is used in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here it was. In the documentation there is a section for that.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/settings/#toc-4